# Color of the Drone console logs

Tags: docker, drone.io

I have a ruby on rails application which I am building using drone. I am running "rspec" as part of my builds. However, the console logs show the output of the rspec only in a plain format. Is there a way I can get these "rspec" logs to show up in colors on the drone console?

PS : I am running a drone docker container on my build machine and I am not using hosted drone.io

Answer (score 0):

Adding something like

```
--color
```

to .rspec should help you with the colorization or to the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Drone currently does not support an interactive shell.

You'll need to add the `--tty` option along with `--color`